# How to iterate over vue components with animation

Tags: html, vue.js, animation, sass

I have would like to make simple appearing effect for anchors from navbar. I've already put `NavigationLink` as inline component and add `scss` styling like this:

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <NavigationLink target="#header" name="About Me" class="trans-nav-1"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <NavigationLink target="#portoflio" name="Portfolio" class="trans-nav-2" />
    </li>
    <li>
     <NavigationLink target="#services" name="Services" class="trans-nav-3" />
    </li>
    <li>
     <NavigationLink target="#contact" name="Contact Me" class="trans-nav-4" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

Version with `v-for` statement:

```
<ul>
  <li
    v-for="navLink in navLinks"
    v-bind:key="navLink.name"
  >
    <NavLink :target="`${navLink.target}`" :name="`${navLink.name}`" :style="style" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

And `scss`:

```
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  from {left: -30vw;}
  to {left: 0; visibility: visible;}
}

@keyframes mymove {
  from {left: -30vw;}
  to {left: 0; visibility: visible;}
}

.trans-nav-1 {
  -webkit-animation: mymove 2s;
  animation: mymove 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-delay: 4s;
  transition: visibility 1s;
}

.trans-nav-2 {
  -webkit-animation: mymove 2s;
  animation: mymove 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.trans-nav-3 {
  -webkit-animation: mymove 2s;
  animation: mymove 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.trans-nav-4 {
  -webkit-animation: mymove 2s;
  animation: mymove 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
```

I want to use `v-for` statement but when I do this animation does not work. Tried to use `<transition>` and `<transition-group>`. Obviously I calculated `animation-delay` in `computed` section but still there is not effect. Is it possible to use `v-for` and simple one `scss` style here for animation effect?

Comment: May I see what you did using `v-for`?

Comment: @CENT1PEDE I edited my question with proper code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
<ul>
  <li
    v-for="(navLink, index) in navLinks"
    v-bind:key="navLink.name"
  >
    <NavLink :target="`${navLink.target}`" :name="`${navLink.name}`" :class="trans-nav-${index + 1}" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can use `v-for` as `v-for="(navLink, index) in navLinks"` to know what current index of the item in the loop. Then, use binding to create a dynamic class like `:class="trans-nav-${index + 1}"`.